# It always works =? it's always work

Tags: grammar, grammaticality-in-context

Between these sentences below, do they have the same meaning? Or is just one of them correct?

1. It always works for me.
2. It's always work for me.

Comment: A bit more context could help here.  Have you found any examples of these two phrases to compare them?     https://www.google.com/search?q=%22It+always+works+for+me%22  or  https://www.google.com/search?q=%22It%27s+always+work+for+me%22  Look at the search results in context.  What is the context in which you want to use the sentence?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Completely different!

Let us try to parse these:

> [It (subject)] [always (adverb, modifying the verb)] [works (verb)] [for me (prepositional phrase)]

Here "works" means "functions correctly". It refers to the machine that may misfunction.

> [It (subject)] [is (verb)] [always (adverb, modifying is)] [work (noun, complement of "It is")] [for me (prepositional phrase)]

So here "work" is a noun meaning "a job", or "a difficult task", except that "work" is non-countable. And "It" must refer to the task.

So the first could be paraphrased as "This machine always functions correctly when I use it." and the second is "This task is always a difficult task for me to perform"

Comment: 'It's always work for me' could be the opposite of 'it's always fun for me'.